# How to get First and last name to work with my ajax script

Tags: php, html, ajax, ms-access

I have an ajax script That gets the post from textbox Employee_Name and auto fills Employee_Number. It works when user types firstname but I want it so when user types first and last name for it to still work. Is it possible to do this?

Here is the insert.php

```
<?php



header('Content-Type: application/json');


try {

$dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
 $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
$Employee_Name=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);  
$Employee_Lastname=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);      
        $params = array( ':FIRSTNAME' => $Employee_Name, ':LASTNAME'=>$Employee_Lastname );

$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM tbl_USERS
    WHERE FIRSTNAME=:FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME=:LASTNAME");

$query->execute($params);

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$EMPLOYEE_NUMBER=trim('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER');
$rc= $result[$EMPLOYEE_NUMBER];

echo json_encode ($rc);

?>
```

The script with the php form.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/view.css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/view.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#Employee_Name").change(function(){
          var Employee_Name=$(this).val();
           if(Employee_Name != ''){
                  $.ajax({
                              type:"post",
                              url:"insert.php",
                              data:"Employee_Name="+Employee_Name,
                              datatype:"json",
                              success:function(data){ $("#Employee_Number").val(data);
                               $('#Employee_Number').css( "background-color","#B3CBD6"  ) 
                               $('#Employee_Number').animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"});
                               },
                                 error: function(response){
    alert("error scripting")    }

                                                           });
           }
           else{
               $("#Employee_Number").val("");
               }

          });
     });



</script>   

<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg1'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-error" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
<body id="main_body" >


    <div id="form_container">


<form class="" action="<?php echo base_url();?>employee/insert_employee" method="post">

        <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Enter Data</h2>

        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Date Scheduled</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="Date_Scheduled" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Employee_Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Employee_Name" name="Employee_Name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 


        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Employee Number </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Employee_Number" name="Employee_Number" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>   


<li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Time Reported </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="Time_Reported" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>   

<li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Reason </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_6" name="reason" required> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
<option value="ILL PTO" >ILL PTO</option>
<option value="PTO" >PTO</option>
<option value="OTHER" >Other</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>

<li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Scheduled Area</label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_4" name="Scheduled_Area" required> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
<option value="Outbound" >Outbound</option>
<option value="Inbound" >Inbound</option>
<option value="Claims" >Claims</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>   


        <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Contact </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_6" name="contact" required> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
<option value="ILL PTO" >ILL PTO</option>
<option value="PTO" >PTO</option>
<option value="OTHER" >Other</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>


        <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Approval </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_6" name="Approval" required> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
<option value="ILL PTO" >ILL PTO</option>
<option value="PTO" >PTO</option>
<option value="OTHER" >Other</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>
          <input id="Complete" class="default" type="hidden" name="Complete" value="NO" />
            <input id="Status" class="default" type="hidden" name="Status" value="1" />

                    <li class="buttons">


                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Dropdown box pulling from acccess db

```
<?php

try {

$dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
 $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
$sql="SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER  FROM tbl_USERS WHERE STATUS='A' order by FIRSTNAME";

/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

echo "<select id='Employee_Name' name=Employee_Name value=''>Employee_Name</option>"; // list box select command
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
echo "<option value=$row[FIRSTNAME] $row[LASTNAME]>$row[FIRSTNAME]  $row[LASTNAME]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the  first and Last Name will be typed in the same input, you could split the string and then separate using a logic for know the First and Last Name:

**Using Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Employee_Name").change(function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    var nameArray = txt.split(",");
    var Employee_Name = nameArray[0];
    var Employee_LastName =  nameArray[1];
    if(Employee_Name != "" && Employee_LastName != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:"Employee_Name="+Employee_Name+"&Employee_Lastname="+Employee_LastName,
            datatype:"json",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            success:function(data){
                $("#Employee_Number").val(data);
                $('#Employee_Number').css( "background-color","#B3CBD6"  ) 
                $('#Employee_Number').animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"});
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert("error scripting");
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#Employee_Number").val("");
    }
    });
});
```

**In PHP:**

```
$Employee_Name = trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);  
$Employee_Lastname = trim($_POST["Employee_Lastname"]);

echo json_encode(explode('.',$rc)[0]);
```

Comment: This is a good way to go wish it was working really stuck on this

Comment: you could test write alerts with the values

Comment: For example: `try {
        Employee_Name = $(this).val().split(' ')[0];
    }
    catch (ex) {
        Employee_Name = $(this).val();
    }   alert(Employee_Name);`

Comment: I will try again tomorrow let you know how it goes

Comment: It is alerting the  firstname. The  lastname says it is undefined

Comment: I edit the **javascript**, can you try it?, the alerts show you the first name, the length when split the string and the last name, the **length is 1 when only write firstname and is 2 when you have firstname and last name**

Comment: I get firstname then 1 the lastname undefined on the alerts

Comment: There is a space in the name like John Doe

Comment: also I am using dropdown does that make a diffrence let me change it to a textbox and see if it works or does samething

Comment: it works with the textbox but it does not autopopulate employee number

Comment: I get First Name then 2 then lastname when typing in textbox but employee number does not auto populate. Also when I was trying before I was using a dropdown for last and firstname

Comment: With textbox the logic works but when use dropdown the logic doesn't work?

Comment: yup I was hoping it would work with dropdown box didn't realize it wouldn't but whit text box I get firstname 2 lastname but the Employee number does not autofill. Would this be possible to use it with dropdown box I wanted to pul the data from db that has two columns firtsname and lastname. I can post up the dropbox above. Sorry for all the troubles.

Comment: typing it is fine to but still not auto populating employee number.

Comment: I edit again the javascript, can you try it with your dropdown?, if the employee number doesn't fill, the problem could be the php

Comment: on the dropdown first name is blank 1 and lastname undefined

Comment: In your code, the field is a input type text, i can't see the dropdown, could you show me the element?

Comment: I think I figured out issue the value is not posting last name and first name without a comma

Comment: Is a comma the separator between last and first name?

Comment: I edit and added my changes I think I have it so far working for dropdown but know I need it to work with a comma like this John,Doe

Comment: yes I inspected the code and it was showing that the dropdown was only getting first name then when I put a comma it worked both names showed up in the value

Comment: but now I can't figure how to get the comma in the js

Comment: it is getting firstname and lastname but not firing the employee number

Comment: Is the ajax execute?, if is the case, the problem is in the PHP code

Comment: what do you mean about the ajax excute

Comment: I mean, if the ajax code is work fine, or something is wrong in the process of execution

Comment: I edit the PHP code, can you try edit your php code in these senteces?

Comment: In your insert.php change these lines: `$Employee_Name=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);  
$Employee_Lastname=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);` for these: `$Employee_Name = trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);  
$Employee_Lastname = trim($_POST["Employee_Lastname"]);`

Comment: omg Ty so much That worked Now to figure how to add the Scheduled_Area too

Comment: Good, finally jaja. That's the solution

Comment: How do i get rid of the.0 at the end of the number?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: 85282.0 it is suppose to be 85282 thats what is in the db

Comment: I think ajax is adding the .0

Comment: In javascript, the code looks like this: `$("#Employee_Number").val(data.substring(0, data.indexOf(".")).replace(".", ""));`

Comment: I have a weird issue the ajax code doesn't want to work unless i hit f12

Comment: I added this and it works now <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        if (typeof console == "undefined") {
            console = {
                log : function () {}
            }
        }
    })();
</script>

Comment: The console object it's not defined on all web browser a

Comment: is this ok to use this

Comment: It's valid but you don't see nothing that you want print

Answer (score 0):

`$("#Employee_Name").change` will fire on the first change event, meaning when the input element loses focus. The best solution would be to use a separate last-name field and fire your ajax post request only when both fields have content.

Comment: what if I do it as a dropdown will it fire the event

Comment: but I have to create a dropdown that will take the firstname and lastname and put it together as one field